# Are the DPDK functions rte_pktmbuf_alloc and rte_pktmbuf_free thread safe?

Tags: dpdk

We have a use-case that has one RX thread and two TX threads operating on same port. The RX thread uses the rte_pktmbuf_free to free the mbuf after processing received packets. The TX threads allocate mbuf using rte_pktmbuf_alloc call and transmit on the port.

When using same pool for RX descriptor init, and for mbuf allocation in TX threads, we see that sometimes there are unexpected mbuf leaks and allocation failures. If we use separate pools for RX and each of the TX threads, then we do not see these issues

We have not used any flags in the mempool_create call. The DPDK documentation seems to indicate mempool operations are thread safe?

We are using DPDK version: 19.11

Are we supposed to create unique mempool for each of the RX and the two TX threads?

EDIT1: Code snippet added as requested by Vipin

## DPDK Primary Process

```
mbuf_pool = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("fast_pkt", 8192,
                256, 0, RTE_MBUF_DEFAULT_BUF_SIZE, rte_socket_id());

/* Configure the Ethernet device. */
retval = rte_eth_dev_configure(port, rx_rings, tx_rings, &port_conf);

/* Allocate and set up 1 RX queue per Ethernet port. */
retval = rte_eth_rx_queue_setup(port, q, 128,
                                rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), NULL, mbuf_pool);

/* Allocate and set up 2 TX queue  */
for (q = 0; q < tx_rings; q++) {
    retval = rte_eth_tx_queue_setup(port, q, 512,
                                rte_eth_dev_socket_id(port), NULL);
}

/* Start the Ethernet port. */
retval = rte_eth_dev_start(port);
```

## Secondary process

### Main thread

```
mbuf_pool = rte_mempool_lookup("fast_pkt");

/* Create rx thread attach it to vCPU #4 */
rte_eal_remote_launch( main_rx, NULL, 4 );


/* create two tx threads and assign affinity to different vCPUs*/
pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, tx_1, NULL );
CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
CPU_SET(5, &cpuset);
pthread_setaffinity_np(thread_id, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset);

pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, tx_2, NULL );
CPU_ZERO(&cpuset);
CPU_SET(6, &cpuset);
pthread_setaffinity_np(thread_id, sizeof(cpuset), &cpuset);
```

### Receive thread (main_rx)

```
for (;; )
{
    nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port , 0, pkts_burst, 32);

    for ( i = 0; i < nb_rx ; i++ )
    {
        process_packet( pkts_burst[ i] );
        rte_pktmbuf_free(pkts_burst[ i]);
    }
}
```

### Transmit threads (tx_1, tx_2)

```
   tx_q = <thread_sepcific queue ID>
   for ( ;; )
   {
         /* Receive Internal message for TX*/
         get_packet ( work_buffer [Burst]);
 
         for ( iterate through each index in work_buffer )
         {  
             tx_mbuf[i] = rte_pktmbuf_alloc(mbuf_pool);
             
             /* combination of following calls to construct packet */
             rte_pktmbuf_mtod( .. );
             /* follow above call with copy from work buffer */

            rte_pktmbuf_prepend( .. );
            rte_pktmbuf_append( .. );
         }

         rte_eth_tx_burst(start_port_id, tx_q, tx_mbuf, num_burst) 

         /* loop through packets not processed by rte_eth_tx_burst */
         for(.. )
         {
             rte_pktmbuf_free (... );
         }
    }
```

Comment: please share your code snippet to better understand your problem

Comment: Hi Vipin - I have put up a simplified snippet that is representative of the DPDK operations/APIs performed by the application in which we are seeing an issue when using a single mbuf pool with multiple threads

Comment: thanks but this is not easy, you are asking me to implement code and check if there is a memory leak issue. there is no information about `process_packet in RX` and `get_packet  in TX`. From the analysis `also you missed out to point out that primary is used for init while secondary does packet processing`. I am not able to find any stats or reference which identified `mbuf alloc failure.`. One should always check for return of rte_pktmbuf_alloc, else ivnalid PTR can lead to malicious TX burst and hang states.

Comment: I will try your code. as per experience `rte_pktmbuf_alloc` and `rte_pktmbuf_free` are therad safe as long as you run 'alloc/free` on separate lcores. I will update that answer but need some time to understand why your code is failing

Comment: Hi Vipin - Thanks for your response. The problem is not very easy to recreate and sometimes takes several hours of continuous run before we start seeing the mbuf leak and depletion of mbuf_pool. So we wanted to understand if the rte_pktmbuf_alloc and rte_pktmbuf_free are intended to be thread-safe or not...

Comment: There are two conflicting statements in the DPDK documentation in this link, about thread safety of mempool library: http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/thread_safety_dpdk_functions.html. This statement indicates mempool libaries may not be thread safe: "certain functions within those libraries may not be safe to call from multiple threads simultaneously. The hash, LPM and mempool libraries and RX/TX in the PMD are examples of this." ..

Comment: However a couple of paragraph later this statement seems to indicate mempool libraries are thread safe: "The mempool library is based on the DPDK lockless ring library and therefore is also multi-thread safe"... One question I have is: Our RX thread uses "rte_eal_remote_launch" whereas our TX threads are created directly using pthread_create from the application. Do you think that makes a difference to thread safety? Should our TX threads also be launched using "rte_eal_remote_launch"?

Comment: I think there is confusion on what is interpreted from DPDK documentation. As you mentioned since it will take hours to reproduce, the easiest approach to the current issue to have quick sync over skype, zoom  or google meet. if the error already occurred at your end, share your screen for easier debug. I think you are missing the point on how mempool is associated with per core cache and global lock. If interested I am open for quick debug

Comment: Hi Vipin - Thanks for the offer to debug. Will check/work out on feasibility and get back to you. Meanwhile, based on your last comment and info available in this link: https://mails.dpdk.org/archives/dev/2013-December/001002.html, Would the following be a correct understanding and an answer to the question posted in the description: Mempool operations are thread-safe as long as the multiple threads accessing the same pool are mapped 1:1 to distinct lcores. In other words, we should not have multiple threads (I.e., pthreads) allocated to same lcore and accessing same memory pool.

Comment: I have hacked a code using DPDK example skeleton to work as priamry-secondary and been running for 2 hours. As mentioned in my comment, if one uses DPDK threads there is no issues or memory leak. But if you launch pthread_create under DPDK threads that is not lcore threads and will have issues.  I had suggested for a quick chat or debug to correct a couple of assumptions, but respect your decision of not having the same.

Comment: I have updated the answer after running the code over 12 hour if it has helped accept and upvote to close the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT-1 answer shared below is a converged questions shared and clarification provided]

1. question-1 `is mempool operations are thread-safe?` - (answer) Yes it is with respect to Lcore DPDK threads.
2. question-2 `Are we supposed to create unique mempool for each of the RX and the two TX threads?` - (answer) No, one can safely use the same mempool across different ports and port-queue pairs alike.
3. question-3 `there is mbuf leak and depletion of mbuf_pool (sample code flow shared in question)` - (answer) after correcting the code, it has been running over12 hours without leaks.
4. question-4 `we wanted to understand if the rte_pktmbuf_alloc and rte_pktmbuf_free are intended to be thread-safe or not` - (answer) Yes
5. question-5 `Our RX thread uses "rte_eal_remote_launch" whereas our TX threads are created directly using pthread_create from the application. Do you think that makes a difference to thread safety? Should our TX threads also be launched using "rte_eal_remote_launch"?` - (answer) yes
6. question-6 `we should not have multiple threads (I.e., pthreads) allocated to same lcore and accessing same memory pool.` - (answer) Yes, that is the right understanding

reason: DPDK lcore threads internally has more things done than `thread create and set affinity`. Please refer [DPDK EAL Documentation for clarity](http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/env_abstraction_layer.html). based on options selected for `rte_eal_init`

1. coremask (hex) is 1:1 CPU logical cores to DPDK lcore threads.
2. lcores (decimal) is 1:1 CPU logical cores to DPDK lcore threads.
3. lcoresmask (decimal) is 1:N, where 1 CPU logical core can be split into `N` DPDK lcore threads.
4. each DPDK lcore threads internally store thread-local variable `index`, which is `rte_lcore_id`
5. hence when one uses `rte_pktmbuf_alloc` it uses the `id` to fetch the cache mempool objects. using the same id on multiple threads violates the lockless model and can cause a hazard if multiple requests come concurrently.

hence rewriting the code snippet with DPDK example `skeleton` in primary-secondary mode with the right API calls does not produce the memory leaks. Stats showcasing the run shared below

```
  ######################## NIC statistics for port 0  ########################
  RX-packets: 15048531    RX-errors:  0           RX-bytes:  1123238216
  RX-nombuf:  0
  TX-packets: 15048504    TX-errors:  0           TX-bytes:  902910240


  ############################################################################

  ######################## NIC statistics for port 0  ########################
  RX-packets: 23424430063  RX-errors:  0           RX-bytes:  1405686130136
  RX-nombuf:  0
  TX-packets: 23424430036  TX-errors:  0           TX-bytes:  1405465802032


  ############################################################################
```

***`RX-nombuf` easily shows if the PMD was not able to get packets due to absence of mbuf***

mempool info

```
========== show - MEMPOOL ==========
mempool <MBUF_POOL>@0x11ff9fad00
  flags=10
  socket_id=1
  pool=0x11ff9eab00
  iova=0xeff9fad00
  nb_mem_chunks=1
  size=8191
  populated_size=8191
  header_size=64
  elt_size=2304
  trailer_size=0
  total_obj_size=2368
  private_data_size=64
  ops_index=7
  ops_name: <ring_mp_mc>
  avg bytes/object=2368.289098
  internal cache infos:
    cache_size=250
    cache_count[32]=171
    cache_count[34]=90
    total_cache_count=261
  common_pool_count=2874
```

note: above stats fetched via dpdk-proc-info utility.

Comment: Thanks Vipin. This comprehensively answers the questions we had on this topic

Comment: @ssrini78 thanks for confirming, I make a humble request to keep the question limited to 1 in next attempt

Comment: Hi @Vipin Varghese - A small clarification on one of the response to "Question-2": "(answer) No one can safely use the same mempool across different ports and port-queue pairs alike."  I beleive there is a "full stop" missing.. Based on other responses I'm interpreting the answer as ""(answer) No. One can safely use the same mempool across different ports and port-queue pairs alike